# Why is length contracted but time is dilated?

Tags: special-relativity

I've just started special relativity and have a quick question on the terminology. From a stationary frame, lorentz transformation gives both length and time of moving frame scaled by the same factor:
$$\Delta x = \gamma \Delta x'\\\Delta t = \gamma \Delta t'$$

Then why does my textbook say length is contracted but time is **dilated**? From the equations, both the length and time are contracted. What am I missing?

Comment: https://youtu.be/-NN_m2yKAAk

Comment: You really need to think about what those changes really represent, and how one measures the length of something that is moving.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens thankyou for that awesome video. I'm still going through them... but both $\Delta x'$ and $\Delta t'$ are smaller than $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$ respectively right?

Comment: The video explains it :) that $\Delta x$ is not the length of an object

Comment: Not particularly conversant in special relativity, but shouldn't gamma be in the denominator of the first equation? See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/tdil.html

Comment: Please state what the delta values actually represent here. Are they for comparing two events?

Comment: @BenCrowell exactly what I need. Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not particularly conversant in special relativity, but I think your first equation is incorrect. Assuming prime designates the moving frame, I believe gamma in the first equation should be in the denominator. Then, given $γ>1$

$$\Delta x=\frac{\Delta x^{'}}{γ}$$

$$\Delta t=γ\Delta t^{'}$$

Where,

$\Delta x^{'}$ is the length of the moving object as measured in the moving frame (proper length), and $\Delta x$ is the length of the moving object as measured in the stationary frame (contracted length).

$\Delta t^{'}$ is the elapsed time of the moving clock as measured in the moving frame (proper time), and $\Delta t$ is the elapsed time of the moving clock as measured in the stationary frame (dilated time).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's true that there is something wrong with the material the OP paraphrases from their text, but that isn't all that's wrong. Actually the way that SR treats the x and t coordinates *is* totally symmetric. What's asymmetric is that a ruler is not analogous to a clock. I discuss this in my answer to the question that this one duplicates.

Comment: @BenCrowell Thanks Ben. I'm a bit new to this myself. Is there anything wrong with my answer?. I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: That was the point of my comment. The equations you give are also wrong if they're just a partial version of the Lorentz transformation -- this gets into the issue of defining the notation, which was never very clear in the OP's statement of this question. In any case, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: So I think the first equation is correct if you apply the correct Lorentz transformation for events that happen simultaneously in the primed frame. I don't think that equation is supposed to represent length contraction.

Comment: So then are the equations given in the above Hyperphysics link also wrong because they appear consistent with mine?

Comment: So Aaron as I asked Ben are they wrong on Hyperphysics because they refer to it as length contraction?

Comment: In the Hyperphysics link they use $t_1=t_2$. The first equation given by the OP is valid for $t_1'=t_2'$ That's why it is not for length contraction, but still a valid equation.

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes it does say the two measurements made in the fixed frame are made simultaneously (t1=t2) and that is the basis of the equation. But it still calls the result "length contraction", does it not?

Comment: Yes. Hyperphysics correctly describes length contraction. I'm saying the equation given by the OP isn't technically incorrect. It just doesn't describe length contraction.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose a rocket going from Earth to Alpha Centauri.

From the rocket frame, the distance between these two locations is shorter than the 4 light years that an Earth observer measures. That is length contraction.

And when the rocket arrives in Alpha Centauri, the clocks of the star (if synchronized to the Earth) will show more time passed than the rocket clocks. That is time dilation.

The logic is to measure the trip distance and duration, and compare with the other frame measurements.

Comment: And when the rocket arrives in Alpha Centauri, his clock will show more time passed than the clocks there — I believe this is wrong. If time dilates, his clock would show less time, not more

Comment: You are right. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity implies equal distance, but either shorter or longer time, so to a person in a car driving on land, and seeing the road as a kilometer would be a contraction of length, but actually the road is 2 kilometers long, dilation of time is also inferred into contraction of distance such that whatever distance we see may take longer time to cover if the velocity of the moving vehicle is constant, and this greatly defines the ideology of spacetime, for example, the sun viewed from the earth seems like the sun is just outside the earth, probably around the same distance as the moon, but in reality, it is millions of miles away from the moon and earth.
In essence,it all depends on the way light behaves and how our eyes can intercept and our brain can interpret the concept of space time.

Answer (score -1):

Length is contracted because we're talking about the length of the object, and time is dilated because we are talking about the scale of the measuring device (length between tics).

It could just have well been "ruler dilation" and "interval contraction".

Comment: One way to see this is wrong is to realize that you're implying that the time and distance phenomena are analogous. Actually they're not, as discussed in my answer to the question that this one duplicates.

Comment: @BenCrowell I am not talking about a physical ruler, I'm talking about "length". A moving yard stick is no longer a yard stick.

Comment: I understand your concept of "**ruler dilation**" -- if the scale of your ruler gets bigger, objects will be measured as **shorter**. But what do you mean by "**interval contraction**"? Time intervals for another observer in respect to you (stationary) also get **dilated**. Do you mind explaining this concept? Do you still consider it to be correct? I can't understand it. Please kindly reply.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying @JEB? Otherwise this is more confusing than helpful to anyone.

Comment: @RobertoValente I don't quite remember, but the $x'$ and $t'$ axes on a Minkowski diagram are completely symmetric, rotated by $\arctan\beta$, with tick marks dilated by $\sqrt{(1+\beta^2)/(1-\beta^2)}$. So time dilation measures an interval $\Delta t'$ at fixed $\Delta x'$, while length contraction is $\Delta x$ at fixed $\Delta t$.